# Second subscription to a shared mapping from BehaviorSubject does not execute

Tags: rxjs, behaviorsubject

When I subscribe to a shared mapping from `BehaviorSubject` instance (`t`), only first subscription is executed.

When the original `BehaviorSubject` (`obj`) emits second value, only the latest value is printed, and both subscriptions were executed.

Let check my code

```
const obj = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(1)
obj.subscribe(console.log)
const t = obj.map(u => {
  console.log("mapped")
  return u * 10
}).share()

t.subscribe(x => console.log("subscribe 1 " + x))
t.subscribe(x => console.log("subscribe 2 " + x))
//with the following line un-commented, both subscriptions print out new value
//obj.next(2)
```

My expected result is

```
1
mapped
subscribe 1 10
subscribe 2 10
```

but the actual result was

```
1
mapped
subscribe 1 10
```

Sorry for the naive question. Is there anyone can explain this to me?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you have two Subjects:

- the `BehaviorSubject` in `obj`.
- `Subject` instance inside `.share()`.

Remember that `BehaviorSubject` emits its cached value **only when you subscribe to it**.

The first observer `obj.subscribe(console.log)` subscribes directly to the `BehaviorSubject`. This prints `1`.

Then you create a chain `t` that ends with the `share()` operator.

Now you subscribe to `t` with `t.subscribe`. This means you subscribe to the `Subject` inside `share()` and since this is its first observer it needs to subscribe to its source Observable (which in turn reaches the source `BehaviorSubject` that emits its cached value). Note that `share()` is just a shortcut for using the [`multicast()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-multicast) operator with `refCount()`.

And the last line you subscribe again with `t.subscribe`. Just like previously this subscribes to the `Subject` inside `share()`. However `share()` already is subscribed to its source Observable so it **doesn't make another subscription**. That's the point of multicasting and the `multicast()` operator.

That's why you won't see any `subscribe 2 10` and you won't event see `mapped` printed twice. You're subscribing to the `Subject` inside `share()`, not the source `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: Do you know how to map a `BehaviorSubject` to another `BehaviorSubject`. I do not want to repeat the logic inside `map` on every subscription, just need this logic run only when the original `BehaviorSubject` instance (`obj`) emits new value. In other word, I want something prints out the result as *expected result* in my question

Comment: I think that I got my answer from @olsn's answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Any operator (including the `share`) actually creates a new Sub-Observable, which has it's own share/replay-properties that are detached from the source-observable.

So to have your result, you should use `publishReplay(1)` instead of `share()`.
(With [`publishReplay`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-publishReplay) you of course have to either use `refCount()` or `connect()`)

```js
const obj = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(1)
obj.subscribe(console.log)
const t = obj.map(u => {
  console.log("mapped")
  return u * 10
}).publishReplay(1)
.refCount();

t.subscribe(x => console.log("subscribe 1 " + x))
t.subscribe(x => console.log("subscribe 2 " + x))
//with the following line un-commented, both subscriptions print out new value
//obj.next(2)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```